# Fractal substitution system

Tags: recurrence-relations, substitution, fractals

It is known that substitution system

$$
A \to ABA, B \to BBB
$$

produces approximations to Cantor set:
$$
A, ABA, ABABBBABA, ABABBBABABBBBBBBBBABABBBABA, \
ABABBBABABBBBBBBBBABABBBABABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBABABBBABABBBBBB\
BBBABABBBABA
$$

I numerically estimated its dimension using naive box-counting method and got the value $D=0.62\pm0.01$

There are many other sequences that have fractal properties:

- Simple kneading sequence: $A \to AB, B \to AA$
- [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence)
- [A self-descriptive fractal sequence](https://oeis.org/A112382)

I tried to estimate their dimensions by various suitable methods, but I always got **about 1**.

So first question is:

Is there an example of a substitution system leading to the appearance of a fractal *different from Cantor set* with a fractal dimension $0 < D < 1$ ?

Second question much more difficult:
Is there *any* example of a substitution system produces [multifractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multifractal_system)?

Comment: I suspect that the [Fibonacci word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word) meets your criterion, but I am not entirely sure that I understand what you mean by the "dimension" (box counting or otherwise) of a string.  Can you more explicitly describe what you mean?  Regarding your second question, multifractals are generally seen as measures with particular scaling properties.  I am not sure how one goes from a string-substitution to a measure---can you please add details about how you expect to get a measure from a substitution process?

Comment: I imagine that anything with $0<D<1$ is going to be "Cantor-set-like," at least in the sense that it can be described as a disconnected subset of a line. All you can really do is change the "spacing" of the points.